# Talking about previous researches. I am looking for verbs similar to "dedicate"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I want to talk about previous researches related to the impact of cell phone radiation. However, I was not very successful in finding proper verbs to construct such sentences. For instance, I wrote

> 1. There are several works<sup>†</sup> dedicated to the investigation of harmful effect of cell phone radiation.
> 2. There are several  works devoted to the investigation of harmful effect of cell phone radiation.
> 3. There are several  works contributed to the investigation of harmful effect of cell phone radiation.
> 4. There are several  works focused on the investigation of harmful effect of cell phone radiation.

Personally, I want to use words similar to "dedicate" or "devote" because they have a connotation of strong commitment, perverse attitude or being completely focused on a subject. However, I am not sure about using "dedicate" in such context.

With this regard,

- Does the two first sentences sound natural, especially in terms of using "dedicate" or "devote"?
- If so, is there any synonym for the verb "dedicate" in this context?

---

<sup>†</sup> ***works*** includes books, articles, journals, and any kind of research papers.

Comment: **about** and **on** are feeling slighted by your insistence on a verb.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to say "perverse attitude". I mean maybe you do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the first two are correct and idiomatic. I would choose the second one. The third is not correct, but "... works which contribute to the investigation of ..." is acceptable. The fourth is also acceptable, the present participle "focussing on" would also be ok.

Note, you have made some pluralisation errors: "... investigation of **the** harmful effect**s**", and research is a non-countable noun, hence "researches" is an error.